# Solvability of Perelman's $\mathcal W$ system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, systems-of-equations, ricci-flow

How to show the system have solution ? $R_{ij}$ is ricci tensor, $R$ is scalar curvature. I feel this is complex question, because I have little knowledge about PDE. So, if it is complex, just tell me what I should read ? I try to find answer in Evans' PDE book, but I am not sure. Whether the 11 chapter of Evans' PDE can resolve this question ?

The below system is from 206 page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> \begin{cases} 
> \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t}=-2R_{ij} \\
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-\Delta f+|\nabla f|^2-R+\frac{n}{2\tau} \\
> \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}=1
> \end{cases}

I try it. Under some initial condition. I can get $\tau=\tau_0+t$. Besides, $\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t}=-2R_{ij}$  has short-time solution, according to the 1.2 of [this](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947). So, it just be whether $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-\Delta f+|\nabla f|^2-R(t)+\frac{n}{2(\tau_0+t)}$ has solution. Because $\tau_0 >0,t\ge0$,and $R(t)$ is smooth...

Comment: You definitely need a solid background in PDE. I would strongly advise also to familiarize yourself with pseudo differential operators. In order to understant the paper you have gave a link, you need thirst of all to understant the ricci flow (Hamilton introduced it and investigated the solvability of it).

Comment: Thanks your advise, I will work hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565591/existence-of-solution-of-frac-partial-f-partial-t-delta-f-nabla-f2-r) is an answer about your question.Let $\tau=t_0-t$, $u=e^{-f}$, then the nonlinear equation will become a linear equation.