# Are there any theorem about the linearization of PDE?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

I am a beginner of PDE, and surprise that some nonlinear equation will become a linear equation after variable substitution,for [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565591/existence-of-solution-of-frac-partial-f-partial-t-delta-f-nabla-f2-r).

So, I am curious that whether there are general theory making equation become linear. If not, why we don't do so ? I want to know the difficult of this way.

Comment: There are no general theories to find a substitution making a non linear PDE linear. There are thousands of cases you can find such a substitutions, just as you are able to solve $x^{6}+ax^{3}+b=0$ but you can't find a general substitution for the 6th grade equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but I am not not familiar with general theory on variable changes that give you linear systems. However, there is GENERAL theory on the topic of linearization around an equilibrium point:

A good starting point is the [Hartmann-Grobman Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem) that tells you that there exists an neighbourhood such that the a linearized system 'resembels' your nonlinear system. There is a lot of theory following this that helps us understand difficult PDEs. [Here](http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0110/0110005.pdf) and [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~kglasner/math585/fixedpointlin.pdf) are two papers that mind interest you.

This is also a [nice book](http://users.uoa.gr/~pjioannou/nonlin/Meiss_Differential_dynamical_systems.pdf) on the topic.

There is also a numerical approach called Propper Orthogonal Decomposition that also gives rise to a linear system.

Comment: Linearization through a change of variables is an exact method, i.e., working the answer back to the original variables solves the original problem. On the other hand, linearization about an equilibrium point is actually a *linear approximation*: the solution to the linear problem does not solve the original problem, it only approximately solves it, and the approximation is best near the equilibrium point. These really aren't at all related techniques.

Comment: Well, I tried to give a general technique involving a linear problem that gives information about a nonlinear problem. I believe there are no GENERAL techniques of transformation to linear problems since they are always problem specific. Since lanse7pty stated that he is new to the topic I thought this might interest him.